# Room Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm developing an Android app where I am creating the database using:

```
Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, WaterDb::class.java, "water.db")
    .createFromAsset("predefined_amounts.db")
    .build()
```

As seen above, I have a Database `predefined_amounts.db`, where I have a table definition like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "AMOUNTS" (
    "amount"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "icon"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("amount","icon")
);
```

The respective entity in Kotlin is:

```
@Entity(tableName = "AMOUNTS", primaryKeys = ["amount", "icon"])
data class Amounts(
    @NonNull val amount: Int,
    @NonNull val icon: String
)
```

This looks okay to me, but when I try to execute, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema: AMOUNTS(me.sparker0i.drinkwater.data.entity.Amounts).
     Expected: TableInfo{name='AMOUNTS', columns={
        icon=Column{name='icon',     type='TEXT',    affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=2, defaultValue='null'}, 
        amount=Column{name='amount', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}}, 
        foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
     Found:
    TableInfo{name='AMOUNTS', columns={
        amount=Column{name='amount', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, 
        icon=Column{name='icon',     type='TEXT',    affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, 
        foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

I have specified `NOT NULL` in the DB and `@NonNull` annotation on the columns in the entity, but still I don't know why `notNull` is coming as `false`.

I dont think the inverted ordering of the columns in expected and found should be a problem, but I dont know why is the `primaryKeyPosition` coming differently? I dont know what is going wrong here.

Comment: Could [this SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62063192/room-exception-on-table-pre-packaged-database-has-an-invalid-schema) be related? It appears that there's a migration involved to handle those null/not/null

Comment: There's no migration needed IMO because this app I'm installing from scratch...

Comment: The primary key position being 0,1 vs 1,2 is very puzzling. What version of Room are you running? Also did you inspect your database to see what the actual schema was? How is the prepackaged DB generated? Is it using the same version of Room? Was it made with the _same_ model object? was it all kotlin or java? (annotation processors are different for both).

Comment: I've not been able to reproduce the failure.  Used [sqlite3](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) to create `predefined_amounts.db` using the SQL you posted.  Successfully used it to pre-populate Room database (Room v2.2.5).  How are you creating `predefined_amounts.db`?  Use `sqlite3` or your SQL tool of choice to view the schema for `predefined_amounts.db` to confirm it's what you expect.

Comment: I'm using DB Browser for SQLite to create the database...

Comment: Ok an export helped.

Comment: I am having this same issue, what do you mean by an export?